# Bash shortcuts do not work in Konsole on Kubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, terminal, kubuntu

I switched from Ubuntu to Kubuntu recently and I noticed that terminal behavior is weird. For example, `Alt+backspace` bash shortcut does not work as expected. It is supposed to remove from the character until the start of the word. Instead, terminal enters into some weird mode when I cannot delete characters with a `Backspace`. Additionally, `Alt+F` bash shortcut does not work as expected (moving cursor one word forward) while `Alt+B` (moving cursor one word back) works fine. That's just some portion of weirdness I noticed, but it is enough to make my work in the terminal a little bit uncomfortable compared to Ubuntu.

Note that I am using bash terminal:

```
$> ls -l /proc/$$/exe
/proc/7362/exe -> /usr/bin/bash
```

Can you hint at how could I achieve normal behavior of the terminal in Konsole (21.12.3) on Kubuntu (22.04)?

Comment: Check whether you can configure keyboard shortcuts for Konsole.

Comment: I can. Alt+backspace and Alt+F are not overridden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to `zsh`. That fixed the problem.